# How can I the plotting afunction in real-time while iteration with help of Seaborn or Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some confusion about plotting.

I wanna plot the cost function `cost` if possible in real-time while iteration with matplotlib or seaborn. **if not static is ok too**.
I don't know how can I start? I found [that](https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/8/14/real-time-graphing-in-python) but it didn't help me too much!

```
def gradient_decent(x,y):
    #Define a start value fo slope (m) and y-intercept (b)
    m_curr=0
    b_curr=0
    iterations=1000
    n=len(x)
    alpha=0.01
    
    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predict=m_curr*x+b_curr # y= m*x + b

        #cost function
        cost=(1/n)*sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predict)]) #List Comperhension

        #Derivation
        d_m=-(2/n)-sum(x*(y-y_predict)) #Derivation r. to m
        d_b=-(2/n)-sum(y-y_predict) #Derivation r. to b
        
        #Updating the values
        m_curr=m_curr-alpha*d_m
        b_curr=b_curr-alpha*d_b

        print("m {}, b {}, cost {}, iterations {} ".format(m_curr,b_curr,cost, iterations))
         
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y=np.array([5,2,8,4,7,9])

gradient_decent(x,y)
```